# Applying Velocity to an object

Tags: three.js, expo

I am trying to make something similar to map controls that will work in a react native app, I have the basics of it working but I've become stuck when trying to make it "scrollable", What I mean is I want to be able to swipe across the screen and sort of fling an object. 
In my mind, the logical way would be to put velocity on the object and gradually make it slow down but I can't find anything like a set velocity in Three Js.

Am I missing something or am I looking at this in the wrong way?

Comment: What you're describing sounds more like 'physics', in which case you could check out Cannon.js (which integrates with THREE.js) - https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/
Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: ill play around with it and let you know thanks, I did look at phsy js it just looked very out of date, Ill try cannon